# Is there a significant difference between a "Reverse Brake Bleeder" and a normal vacuum pump bleeder?

Tags: brakes, bleeding

I was hoping someone could explain these products and if they feel led, put their 2 cents in about brake bleeding. My brakes are slightly insensitive right now, even though they work and I'm considering purchasing a 50 dollar reverse brake bleeder online so I could ensure they are working the best for this upcoming winter.

**Update:**
While the answers and comments are useful, I still want to get at the root of the question which I will try to word better. For example, if the Mityvac 8500 can create positive and negative pressure with a switch on the apparatus, how is using it with positive pressure at the bleeder not exactly the same as a "reverse" bleeder?

Comment: For many vehicles, the "old school" method of pushing on the brake pedal and opening the bleed valve was usually sufficient...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Reverse bleeder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00GRV800S) pumps brake fluid from the caliper bleed screw back to the master cylinder. This type is hard to use because Master Cylinders do not have bleed screws to connect to.

[Vacuum pump](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00265M9SS) is the opposite, it sucks brake fluid from the Master Cylinder when connected to the brake bleeder on the caliper. **Note: some vacuum pumps on the market can create positive or negative pressure, making some capable of reverse bleeding.**

There is one more option called a [pressure bleeder](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005MVBFM4), but they are expensive and you have to have the correct Master Cylinder adapter cap for your vehicle.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation of these three? You'd mentioned the Reverse Bleeder is hard to use. It seemed liked a great option since it allows bubbles to go the direction they are already going, but I have little experience bleeding brakes.

Comment: I have always used the Vacuum bleeder.

Comment: Moab, I provided some clarification in my question. Do you think you could take a stab at providing your insight with that portion of the question? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't think one is better at bleeding than another, its a matter of preference.

Comment: So, I could "reverse" bleed with a normal vacuum bleeder (assuming it can create positive or negative pressure)?

Comment: Vacuum bleeder cannot make pressure.

Comment: Mine can push air or suck air.

Comment: But can it push fluid?

Comment: Yes. I found the answer: Some vacuum bleeders can reverse bleed too, like the one I've mentioned here. It can push fluid or pull fluid (vacuum or pressure).